# app.exe.config file reading

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

While debugging a web service issue (client side is a windows desktop application developed under c#, that consumes a web service), I have encountered the following situation.
Application.exe.config file on the PC that builds the release files, is read by the application on startup, whenever I copy the directory to another PC (Some PCs and not all), the configuration file is no longer being read.
I have been able to get to the latter conclusion, by simulating the below scenario.
The App.exe.Config file is listed:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2"/>
    </startup>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="WebServiceSoap" />
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:6608/WS_POSsync.asmx" binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="WebServiceSoap" contract="ServiceReference1.WebServiceSoap"
                name="WebServiceSoap1" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

When I mess with this file (by adding some words in the beginning, thus making the XML inconsistent, the application throws an exception, therefore it seems that it is trying to fetch the file. 
When I deploy the same folder on another PC, and repeat the same scenario, the executable seems to run normally.

Any clarification on this matter is appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you are edit the correct file? The file will have the same name as the executable but append `.config` at the end. Example: `MyApplication.exe` would have an app.config of `MyApplication.exe.config` and that is the file that would be read when the `MyApplication.exe` launches.

Comment: Yes of course, the exact same file

Comment: What folder are you deploying? Is it possible you are editing the bin/debug config (for instance), but running the bin/release executable?

Comment: No, I am deploying the bin/release folder all the files inside are generated by the build operation.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was not related to any configuration issues, I have found that the client PC was infected with a Trojan that changed the original filename whenever a file is copied. By terminating the Trojan (Dibifu_9) process and pasting the files, the issue was solved.